# Unable to send data from view (razor) to controller via ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

here is the controller

```
public ViewResult AddNewRow(ProjectBudgetModel model)
{
   //Some oprations goes here on the passed model the return to the same view 
   return View("AddNewProjectBudget", model);
}
```

here is the view which has the ajax call like

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddNewRow", "ProjectBudget")',
            type: 'post',
            data: {model: '@Model'},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.success)
                return;
            },
            error: function (x) {                
                alert(x.status);
            }
        });
```

@Model which is passed in the data header in the ajax call is ProjectBudgetModel

something goes wrong here specifically while i pass the data to the controller 
it even doesn't hit the brekpoint of the addNewRow function in controller

any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
data: {model: '@Model'},
```

doesn't do at all what you think it does. Look at the generated markup to see that this emits some broken values.

It should be like that:

```
data: JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),
```

The `JSON.stringify` method is natively built-into modern browsers. If for some reasons you need to support browsers from the stone age, you could include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to your page which will define the method.

Comment: @roasted, of course there were. Internet Explorer 6 is a great example of such a browser. I remember [`Fred Flintstone`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Flintstone) talking about having encountered problems with it when surfing the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to send the data from the view to the model on controller was using:

`data: $("#FORM_ID").serialize(),`

If I use the: data: `JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),` the controller receives a empty model.